# Could not load file or assembly Kendo.Mvc, Version=2017.3.913.545

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Under development in Visual Studio, everything works fine. But after deployment to IIS server it raises Server Error.

This is happening after upgrading from 2017.3.913.545 to 2017.3.2016, getting error in new Controller only. Previous controllers are working.

Error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Kendo.Mvc, Version=2017.3.913.545, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Tried GACUTIL, but version error.

Command Prompt:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64>gacutil /i "E:\Jignesh.Surti\TFS\C3i Web App\C3Connect.C3i\lib\KENDOUIMVC\2017.3.1026.545\Kendo.Mvc.dll"

Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 3.5.30729.1

Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Failure adding assembly to the cache:   This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: New version is "2017.3.1026.545"

Comment: Third try in command prompt with new GACUTIL:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64>gacutil /i "E:\Jignesh.Surti\TFS\C3i Web App\C3Connect.C3i\lib\KENDOUIMVC\2017.3.1026.545\Kendo.Mvc.dll"

Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache.

But issue has not resolved yet in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

It's resolved after adding reference dll from install folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC R3 2017\wrappers\aspnetmvc\Binaries\Mvc5\Kendo.Mvc.dll

But doesn't work if you reference it from some other folder like "library" folder.

Don't know why it is like that!